# Отличие пакетов и библиотеки (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

Решил я значит использовать jquery. Но вот на этапе установке у меня возник вопрос. Я могу использовать файл jquery.js или могу использовать "npm install jquery" в консоли. В первом случае мы имеем 1 файл, в другом прям пакет файлов. Но это должно быть одно и то же. Или нет? В чем разница-то?

Comment: Пакет - это библиотека, которую можно установить через пакетный менеджер, она специально запакована и подготовлена для такой установки. Под катом может оказаться как той же библиотекой, которую можно скачать с оффсайта, так и чем-нибудь более специфическим. Например, если вам нужно решить задачу с использованием JQuery, которой в свою очередь для решения понадобятся еще другие библиотеки, то вы можете получить целую россыпь новых файлов и директорий в NPM.  Вообще в случае NPM вы никогда не получите 1 файл после npm install *libName* - [Подробнее](https://habr.com/post/307822/)

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае вы используете скрипт для загрузки jQuery, а во втором случае у вас создается модуль в Node.js. После чего вы можете использовать `require('jquery')` для загрузки jQuery.

Comment: Иии...? В чем разница?

Comment: Скрипт не загружает определение модуля.